# Unable to get the SLD file of existing style in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am trying to access some specific geoserver styles but I get an error page:

```
HTTP Status 404 -
The requested resource () is not available.
```

This is the URL I use:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/styles/polygon.sld
```

I use Geoserver 2.7 and the style exists.

If I try this:

```
 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles/polygon.sld
```

Then I get a file with the SLD.

When I try with other styles, which I have defined it works properly.

Comment: what made you think http://localhost:8080/geoserver/styles/polygon.sld would work? AFAIK it has never been a way to the style.

Comment: Hmmm.. but it works for other styles. Can you please recommend what is the way to get the SLD of a style?

Comment: Well there you are, either use the REST api or skip over the "builtin" styles of line, point, polygon and generic.

Comment: OK. But I don't quite understand why the "builtin" styles don't work.

Comment: because there is no polygon.sld file - look in data_dir/styles/ to check